# WPF : Mouse hover Disabled when popup is open .( Popup takes Mouse Event)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, popup, mouseevent, mouseover

In my Application I have popup, when I open the popup it steals the mouseEvents for other controls. So due to which Mousehover states doesn't trigger for other controls(ex.Buttons).MouseOver States are defined using VisualStates.

```
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{DynamicResource ControlHoveredBackgroundColor}" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

How to get MouseOver when popup is in opened State?.

Comment: A popup is a separate window.  You'd do better using a panel inside whatever the thing is you want to mouse over.

Comment: I have buttons and popup , when I open the popup it steals the mouseEvents for other controls.

Comment: Don't use a popup.